# CPU usage intermittently at 100%

Tags: 16.04, cpu

CPU usage on our metrics box is at 100% intermittently causing:
*'Internal server error'* when rendering Grafana dashboards

The only application running on our machine is Docker with 3 subcontainers

The following is our configuration details:
 3 subcontainers running\
  cadvisor\
  graphite\
  grafana\
 **Driver status**\
  Docker Version 17.09.0-ce\
  Kernel Version 4.4.0-103-generic\
  OS Version Ubuntu 16.04 LTS\
 **Storage**\
  Driver -> overlay2\
  Backing Filesystem -> extfs\
  Supports d_type -> true\
  Native Overlay Diff -> true

Memory swap limit -> 2.00GB

Here is a snippet from cAdvisor:

[image]

**Question**: Is there a way to reduce the CPU usage?

Comment: The community has reversed your decision to delete this post as we determined that this Q & A was useful to future readers. If for some reason you don't wish to be associated with it, Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-cc-by-sa-3-0

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is yes. The long answer is likely that someone attempted to configure container access to the host CPU cycles and configured incorrectly.

> By default, each container’s access to the host machine’s CPU cycles is unlimited. You can set various constraints to limit a given container’s access to the host machine’s CPU cycles. Most users will use and configure the default CFS scheduler. In Docker 1.13 and higher, you can also configure the realtime scheduler.

You need to

> Configure the default CFS scheduler
>
> The CFS is the Linux kernel CPU scheduler for normal Linux processes. Several runtime flags allow you to configure the amount of access to CPU resources your container has. When you use these settings, Docker modifies the settings for the container’s cgroup on the host machine.

You can Specify how much of the available CPU resources a container can use, as well as Limit the specific CPUs or cores a container can use among several other options relating to CPU usage configuration. For more, check the source.

**Warning:** CPU scheduling and prioritizing are advanced kernel-level features. Most users do not need to change these values from their defaults. Setting these values incorrectly can cause your host system to become unstable or unusable.

I personally would cautiously assign 1/4 of the CPU cores available to each container leaving some wiggle room for other things. So on a quad core running docker v1.13 and higher:

I'd `docker run -it --cpus="1" ubuntu /bin/bash`

and on v.1.12 and lower:

I'd `docker run -it --cpu-period=100000 --cpu-quota=25000 ubuntu /bin/bash`

This appears to be a good starting point for a quad core system. I would tune these parameters to obtain the level of performance vs. availability that I desired.

Source:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/resource_constraints/#configure-the-default-cfs-scheduler